# OSX unable to access samba4 shares

Tags: mac-osx, samba4

As the question states, I have an OSX client that is currently not a member of the domain.

I am trying to access the SMB shares of the samba4 (Go to server -> smb://server) and I am being prompted to enter my username and password.

When I enter my password nothing happens, Finder remains in a "Connecting..." state but it never connects. I've tried to get a tcpdump to see the exchanged packets and I think that the password is never sent across but I might be wrong.

I've also tried to enable debugging on samba4 but I couldn't make something out of it.

Note that the username I am using, logs in properly from Windows clients. Samba5 has been configured by following the tutorial found here https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

Could you please help me debug this?

EDIT:

As requested, OSX client is 10.8.4. It is not a member of the domain and just tries to access the share files using the username/password in the domain controller (Samba4)

Comment: The last 3 versions of OSX all used different implementations of Samba, to diagnose this further you're going to have to be a little more specific. What Version(s) of OSX are you running, is this using domain authentication etc.

Comment: @AlexBerry I've updated the question as requested

Answer (score 1):

I solved all my Apple+Samba issues by also installing Netatalk (AFPd) on the server in question... 'They' say the Apple SMB implementation is really poor.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit on this? So just installing afpd will make samba4 work? Is this an alternative?

Comment: @mobius It's an alternative. You just make that data available through another service as well. You have to install it, and configure your share. Apple clients will connect with AFP and Windows with SMB.